# String error when adding items from a listbox to an access database

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add the items in a list box to an access database. However at first, I was getting an error message saying the `syntax was missing` but now, I seem to get `Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid ERROR`. I've researched into this and it says it's because there may be a textbox empty but the listbox has many items in it which is what I'm not sure on.

Help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
 Dim vari1 As String
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        MyConn.Open()
        Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, MyConn)
        Try
            For i As Integer = 0 To LstOrderItems.Items(i) - 1
                vari1 = LstOrderItems.Items.Item(i).ToString
                cmd1.CommandText = ("insert into RestaurantData ([Food Order]) VALUES(" + vari1 + ")")
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        MyConn.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this line is your problem:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To LstOrderItems.Items(i) - 1
```

You're trying to read the item at index `i` (which is currently 0) as a number to loop to.

I think what you meant to write was this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To LstOrderItems.Items.Count - 1
```

As for your database error you are missing two single quotes. When inserting data you must surround every value inside `VALUES()` with single quotes.

For instance:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES('column1 value', 'column2 value', 'column3 value')
```

So to fix your error you must add those single quotes as well:

```
cmd1.CommandText = ("insert into RestaurantData ([Food Order]) VALUES('" + vari1 + "')")
```

Though you should really look into [**Parameterized queries**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) (aka *Prepared statements*) since your code is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

See [***How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) for more info.

Comment: That is what I had before, however now it's gone back to say `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression`

Comment: @Matthew : That's related to your database query and not the loop. What I've shown above is one of the correct ways to iterate every item of the `ListBox`.

Comment: @Matthew : I have updated my answer with a fix to your database query as well.

Comment: @Matthew : Glad I could help! Good luck!